# Google Web App Script Daily Update for Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Hello in my below link i have a user form were i can add, edit and delete a user.

Spreadsheet Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tyz_3WeEkmY4WX8Xvx38nkLow8hcbCjPMLS1-NiPFgo/edit?usp=sharing

Dev Link
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxIT4fJPNyD5U2CKFzWCSho0tR2uuczq1hevzHawtg/dev

So now all the above fields like name, email, date of birth will be saved and can be re-edited.

I added 2 more column below Phone Number & Country
`Daily Updates`  and  `Daily Logs`

Now when i edit a user and update today's activity in `Daily Updates` like `Something added on - 1-jan-2021`
Now it should clear field in `Daily Updates` and should be updated in `Daily Logs field`.
If i update `Something added on 2-jan-2021` in `Daily Updates` again it should be cleared and appear in `Daily Logs` field as previous and current

`Something added on - 1-jan-2021`

`Something added on 2-jan-2021`

So my goal is display all changes done to `Daily Updates` field should be appear in `Daily Logs` field as read only this can't be edited.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I updated my script above and added 2 text Input ```Daily Updates``` and
```Daily Logs``` .  now when i edit a user and update today activity in ```Daily Updates``` like ```Something added on - 1-jan-2021```  Now it should clear field in ```Daily Updates``` and should be updated in ```Daily Logs``` field.  again if i update ```Something added on - 2-jan-2021``` in ```Daily Updates```   again it should be cleared and appear in ```Daily Logs``` field as ```Something added on - 1-jan-2021```  ```Something added on - 2-jan-2021```.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the value is loaded by editing data from "Contact Details Database" and inputting the value to "Daily Updates" and clicking "Submit" button, you want to save the value to "Daily Logs" and want to clear "Daily Updates".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify the function `updateData` in Google Apps Script side as follows.

##### From:

```js
function updateData(values, spreadsheetId, range) {
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, { valueInputOption: "RAW" });}
```

##### To:

```js
function updateData(values, spreadsheetId, range) {
  var len = values[0].length;
  values[0][len - 1] = values[0][len - 1] ? `${values[0][len - 1]}\n${values[0][len - 2]}` : values[0][len - 2];
  values[0][len - 2] = "";

  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, { valueInputOption: "RAW" });
}
```

- By this modification, when the data is updated, the value of "Daily Updates" is saved to "Daily Logs" as the additional value and "Daily Updates" is cleared.

#### Note:

- From `Daily Logs field as read only this can't be edited.`, in this case, please put `readonly="readonly"` to the textarea tag of "Daily Logs".

### Added:

From the following reply,

> IF i add more fields like Last name , job field, etc,,, i keep adding extra columns in spreadsheet.

In this case, how aobut using the column number as follows?

#### To:

```js
function updateData(values, spreadsheetId, range) {
  var colDailyChanges = 8; // Column "H"
  var colDailyLogs = 9; // Column "I"
  values[0][colDailyLogs - 1] = values[0][colDailyLogs - 1] ? `${values[0][colDailyLogs - 1]}\n${values[0][colDailyChanges - 1]}` : values[0][colDailyChanges - 1];
  values[0][colDailyChanges - 1] = "";

  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, { valueInputOption: "RAW" });
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Its working thanks.  but do i need to change anything in ```function updateData```   if i keep adding more fields and columns in google sheet ?

Comment: @Demotry Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `but do i need to change anything in function updateData if i keep adding more fields and columns in google sheet ?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I added 1 more field ```Last``` in my script   now the changes to ```Daily Updates``` not moving to ```Daily Logs```

Comment: @Demotry Thank you for replying. In your situation, you want to add more columns to Spreadsheet. About this, you want to reflect this to the modification point. I understood like this. If my understanding is correct, how aobut using the column number? So I added one more modification point in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike Its working and Its really good as i imagined.

Comment: @Demotry Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about it? If my answer was not useful, I have to apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239956/discussion-between-demotry-and-tanaike).